# How to use is current year from carbon library on sonata

Tags: php, sonata

I am new at sonata and i am trying to use the carbon library to generate an output of all the records from this year.

*This is from the carbon library 
Carbon::isCurrentYear
no arguments
returns bool
Checks if the instance is in the same year as the current moment.
Method added    1.22.0  no arguments*

The following is the code i am trying to apply

```
 public function getIsActiveThisYear(): bool
    {
        $now = Carbon::isCurrentYear();
        $endofyear = $endDate->year;
        $startofyear = $startDate->year;
        return $this->$endofyear == $now || $this->$startofyear == $now;  
    }
```

The error as a result of this code is:

```
isCurrentYear does not exist
```

Comment: Carbon::isCurrentYear  is not static method of class it can be called something as `$date->isCurrentYear()`. By the way other your  code is meanless too

Comment: $endDate- and startDate are undefind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$date = new DateTime(); // Carbon extends the PHP DateTime class so it's the same.
$thisYear = $date->format('Y');
```

Check the docs! :-)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

You will also need to pass your start and end dates

```
public function getIsActiveThisYear(DateTime $startDate, DateTime $endDate): bool
```